# Maxent POS tag table

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I use `nltk.pos_tag` for part-of-speech tagging which use `maxent part of speech tagger`. I need a table of all available tags.

My ultimate aim is to extract just the adverbs and adjectives from a text.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pos_tag`, according to its docstring, uses "NLTK's currently recommended part of speech tagger", so the validity of this advice might expire. For reproducible results, use an explicit POS tagger object.

Looking at the [source code for `pos_tag`](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/nltk/nltk/tag/__init__.py), we can see that it calls

```
>>> nltk.data.load('taggers/maxent_treebank_pos_tagger/english.pickle')
```

from which we can get a list of POS tags with

```
>>> _.classifier().labels()
['PRP$', 'VBG', 'VBD', '``', 'VBN', 'POS', "''", 'VBP', 'WDT', 'JJ', 'WP', 'VBZ',
 'DT', '#', 'RP', '$', 'NN', 'FW', ',', '.', 'TO', 'PRP', 'RB', '-LRB-', ':',
 'NNS', 'NNP', 'VB', 'WRB', 'CC', 'LS', 'PDT', 'RBS', 'RBR', 'CD', '-NONE-',
 'EX', 'IN', 'WP$', 'MD', 'NNPS', '-RRB-', 'JJS', 'JJR', 'SYM', 'UH']
```

(I must admit I found this out using object inspection and trial-and-error.)

The adjectives and adverbs would be at least the categories `JJ` (adj) and `RB` (adv), plus perhaps `VBN` (past participle, e.g. "tired").

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import nltk
nltk.help.upenn_tagset()
# and
nltk.help.brown_tagset()
```